# WordPress: How to style gallery shortcode into masonry layout?

Tags: css, wordpress, gallery, image-gallery

I'm trying to make a masonry layout possible through using (placing this in the page content section):

`[gallery size="large" link="file" columns="4" ids="1,2,3"]`

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

But even though this is the desired effect:

[image: desired masonry effect]

This is what keeps happening:

[image: Realistic masonry effect]

Essentially, if there was some CSS or even javascript that could be added to transform the gallery to do this, would be fantastic.

My code at the moment, looks like this:

```
<div class="gallery-template">
    the_content();
</div>
```

And my additional css is:

```
.gallery-template img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: none !important;
}
.gallery-item{
    width: 33% !important;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

This doesn't exactly do anything to solve the problem of when a new section of thirds starts, to get rid of the `padding` and `margin` between the "rows".

When the `[gallery]` shortcode mentioned above gets rendered, the way it's rendered in the DOM is like so:

```
<div class="gallery-template">
    <div id="gallery-1" class="gallery">
        <dl class="gallery-item">...</div>
        <dl class="gallery-item">...</div>
        <dl class="gallery-item">...</div>

        // And so on..
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS rendered in the DOM is:

```
#gallery-1 {
    margin: auto;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-item {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.gallery-item {
    width: 33% !important;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Has anyone implemented a solution for this sort of obstacle yet?

**Also, I'm trying to refrain from using an external plugin.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! I was able to get this working. Here's my solution:

First, it was necessary to prohibit the *gallery shortcode* to inject external styles into the page. So in the `funtions.php` file, I added:

```
add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );
```

Next, I took out the column specification in the *shortcode* tag I was incorporating in the page, like so:

```
[gallery size="large" link="file" ids="1,2,3"]
```

Rather than:

```
[gallery size="large" link="file" columns="4" ids="1,2,3"]
```

Lastly, I placed this **CSS** into my page (including the `column-count`):

```
.gallery-template{margin:auto; column-count:4;column-gap:0;}
.gallery-template img{max-width:100%;height:auto;border:none !important;}
.gallery-item{margin:0;display:inline-block;width:100%;width:100%;margin-top:0;}
```

**EXTRA:** If you are looking to make this responsive, simply add the `@media` tags where you want your preferred breakpoints, and place in the new number of columns, like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    .gallery-template{column-count:3;}
}

@media screen and (max-width:772px) {
    .gallery-template{column-count:2;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is, indeed, a css question.  I would suggest checking out [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  Creating an entire solution for you will be a little tricky since you haven't posted your html, so if this exact code doesn't work, try editing your post to include some of it.

```
#gallery-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.gallery-item {
    flex: 0 1 33%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I tried this, and unfortunately it didn't work. This however, did work for a non-WordPress instance :). I'll upvote for the help!

Comment: The basic strategy will work irrespective of whether it is wordpress or not.  However, you may have to override some css on the WP site.  If the site has a public url, I'd be willing to take a look at it and give you more specific css.

Comment: Yes, I believe there was a massive amount of injected WP CSS. Not to worry, I'll play with it on my own time. Once again, thanks! :)